# Does AdS/CFT help solve the singularity of a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, singularities, geodesics, ads-cft

How does thinking of a black hole as encoding its information in its surface help solve what happens inside it, more specifically geodesic incompleteness. Doesn't it tell us that if we can see how light (or matter) behaves around the horizon we can predict what it does inside the black hole

Answer (score 3):

It does not solve what happens inside. The information on the horizon, by the entanglement of virtual particles with the particles that passed, keeps track of the state of the particles inside. The momenta of the infalling particles are entangled with these virtual ones on the horizon. So in a sense the inside physics can be seen on the horizon. The entanglement can last because time has virtually stopped wrt to faraway observers. The Hawking radiation emerging from these virtual particles is seen to radiate over a long time faraway. But in the hole it takes very small time. Maybe the singularity isn't even formed before evaporation.